# cannot access my webpage from outside (xampp)

Tags: apache, web, xampp, router, portforwarding

I am trying to set up a web server with Xampp (ver 7.0.13) on my home PC. I redirect port 80 from router to my PC and Xampp is listening to port 80. Also, I change router's web server's port to 8080 in order to avoid conflict.

Result: I can access my ***helloworld.html*** on my pc and my phone. However, If i turn off my iphone wi-fi and using 4G network, I will not able to access dashboard and my ***helloworld.html*** by public ip (56.XXX.XXX.XXX/helloworld.html)

I try :

1. reinstall xampp
2. try different version off xampp
3. change config file >> Order deny,allow from all  (something like that
4. try to change  but  cannot be found in most of the config files.
5. change router port forward setting.

But nothing work. What did I do wrong? ┐(´д`)┌

Comment: Can you access your helloworld.html from your PC via 56.XXX.XXX.XXX/helloworld.html ?

Comment: @actc yes I can access helloworld.html from my PC

Comment: @JasonLi, I have the same problems as yours. Any updates ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe external traffic is blocked by the Windows-Firewall?

Comment: I turn off windows firewall and turn off AVG's firewall and other functions. Still not able to access my website

Answer (score 0):

Is it a static IP? You should use a static IP in your server, if not, is impossible

Comment: I set my pc ip to 192.168.11.88 and router is forwarding the port to this 192.168.11.88  but it is still not working.

Comment: It seems that this is your private address. You should give access to your public IP address

Comment: No, I am using public ip. My router has set up port forward, router will forward its port 80 to my pc's (192.168.11.88) port 80. And I still not able to use my router's ip (56.XXX.XXX.XXX) to browse my website